# Maven Build Error - Firefly Plugin - No plugin found

Tags: java, maven, vaadin8

I have tried several methods to resolve this issue.
I am trying to install the Vaadin Starter App "Bakery"
Version using : Java, Shiro, Vaadin Platforms.

Error on build failure:
No plugin found for prefix 'firefly' in the current project and in the plugin groups

I've tried methods listed [here][1]
and another post by deleting my .m2/resources and letting it repopulate. and also a mvn clean install, but I keep getting same error messages.
Here is a [link][1] to the error messages:

Above the plugin error are some type of fetch cant get meta data messages.

I'm thinking it needs a different version of a plugin, needs pom file or settings file edited, but just have not found solution yet.

No plugin found for prefix 'firefly' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened to my links in post : https://pastebin.com/k58SthdK

Comment: what about your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was with the plugin causing a problem. I went to this link, found the file, over-wrote the existing file with the one at the link, did a rebuild and it worked.

[Maven-compiler-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-plugins/blob/master/maven-compiler-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilationFailureException.java)